# using 'BFC' allocator with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory

I get outofmemory with my model which is an extension of InceptionV3 together with image size (324,486,3).

The error is

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,38,58,64]
```

And the model is defined as:

```
inceptModel = InceptionV3(include_top=False ,weights='imagenet', input_shape=(324,486,3))
for layer in inceptModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

z = inceptModel.outputs    
z = Flatten(name='custom_flt')(z)
z = Dense(1024)(z)

z = Activation('relu')(z)
z = Dense(1, input_dim=1024)(z)
z = Activation('linear')(z)
model = Model(inputs=inceptModel.input, outputs=z)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history_callback = model.fit(x_img_smal, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

After reading this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/136

i tried defining BFC allocator in Keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
sess = tf.Session(config = config)

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
```

But I suspect it is overwriting some default config in for tensorflow - used in Keras. Because I got a new error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Adam_4/iterations
         [[Node: Adam_4/iterations/read = Identity[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@Adam_4/iterations"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Adam_4/iterations)]]
```

This might be because Im overwriting some default config with:

```
K.set_session(sess)
```

Is it possible to get hold of the current tensorflow config and instead append to that - with the BFC config?

I was able to avoid the memory issue by setting batch_size=1 in fit()

But setting batch_size=2 gives another error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,425984], In[1]: [212992,1024]
         [[Node: dense_3/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](custom_flt_1/Reshape, dense_3/kernel/read)]]
         [[Node: metrics_1/acc/Mean_1/_3311 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4991_metrics_1/acc/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

(edit: added last error - case)

Comment: What is your batch size? And your GPU memory?

Comment: GPU is 12 Gig - using one P100. The code above is alittle inaccurate. Used a batch_size=32 but I didnt use fit(), but fit_generator()

Comment: Remove the code where you are trying to use `BFC` allocator and run the code again. If it throws error, paste the error snapshot here so that I can take a look

Comment: Using z = inceptModel.output instead of outputs fixed the problem.